# nginx location - proxy_pass behaviour differs when used with or without trailing slash - why?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to understand why the following configurations do not behave the same:

```
location /external/partner {
    proxy_pass https://api.partner.com;
}
```

and

```
location /external/partner/ {
    proxy_pass https://api.partner.com/;
}
```

When performing a call to:
http://my.nginx/external/partner/component/getInfo

I do understand that the version with the trailing slash is cleaner, to avoid matching something like /external/partner**s** for example, but I'd still like to understand the difference in behaviour, as it's my current (obviously wrong) understanding that what should reach the upstream element would be the same in both cases.

Config tested on nginx 1.19.6 and 1.20.9, same behaviour.

Comment: They are totally different. The second example contains [an optional URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) which causes the request to change - the first does not, so the request passes through unmodified.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for the link and the comment, it clarifies a lot the behavior. Thanks to you I'll review my configs and correct such things.